# ImageMagick's convert command is crashing with certain GIFs

Tags: imagemagick, gif, imagemagick-convert

I'm running the following command on my server for user-uploaded images:

```
convert "original.gif" -coalesce -auto-orient -layers "optimize" "new.gif"
```

This works on most GIFs but hangs forever on certain ones, including [this one](https://a.uguu.se/EFE2AoMsONp0_original.gif).

Any idea as to why that is? The failing GIFs may have already been resized using gifsickle, wondering if that might be the cause and how to detect this.

I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.8-9 Q16 x86_64. However the same thing occurs on 6.8. The process is using 16GB of memory.

Comment: You can try using ImageMagick-7 with Q8, which may improve decoding speed. But applying `-coalesce` on GIF with 1.5k frames can be rather resource intensive. Perhaps more than what the server can handle.

Comment: That peaks at 19GB of RAM on my Q16 version of ImageMagick. Try running `identify -list resource` to see how much memory you permit ImageMagick.

Comment: It's allowed 16GiB. Will look into screening for GIFs with many frames.

Comment: See if you are allowed to run `convert -limit memory 24MiB original.gif -coalesce -auto-orient -layers optimize new.gif`

Comment: It still appears to be hanging with `-limit memory 24MiB`

Comment: I have to ask, but what is this command attempting to do? Coalesce reverses the optimized layers, auto-rotate applies rotation based off EXIF (not present in GIFs), and finally reapply optimizing layers. I wouldn't be surprised if "new.gif" is larger than "original.gif".

Comment: I don't know. The image processor is running this on all images before resizing.